# Working with JSON to retrieve and access data in a windows application using c#

Tags: c#, javascript

This is part of my JSON:

```
{
    "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-2",
    "Title": "Cran Berry Feta Pinwheels",
    "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 2",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/baby kato.jpg",
    "Description" : "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis",
    "Content" :["Cran Berry Feta Pinwheels", 
                "1 (170 g) package dried sweetened cranberries",
                "1 (250 g) container cream cheese spread",
                "1 cup crumbled feta cheese",
                "1/4 cup chopped green onion",
                "4 large flour tortillas or 4 large wheat flour tortillas or 4 large spinach tortillas"


    ]},
```

I want it to retrieve data in that order. It is a Windows 8.1 application project in ItemPage.xaml. I am using this code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" 
               Margin="0,12,0,0"
               Height="200" 
                Stretch="UniformToFill" />

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" 
                   Margin="10,12,10,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

If I use the dummy data provided by Microsoft in it works but if I edit it like I did above in content, I get an exception:
An exception of type:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was
>   not handled in user code

WinRT information: This is not a string value. Use ValueType property to get the type.

Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time.

It then highlights this line of code:

```
var sampleDataGroups = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupsAsync();
```

I am an absolute beginner in Windows development.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the method that that line of code comes from? and the code for GetGroupsAsync() method as well? Very few of us are clairvoyant enough to know what your code does without seeing it.

Comment: The type of the Content property you binding for must be a string. Check the type of the Content prop (it is binded to one of the sampleDataGroups i suppose).

Comment: private async Task GetSampleDataAsync()
        {
            if (this._groups.Count != 0)
                return;Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject["Groups"].GetArray();